# Using Akka.net / Actor System for an ETL process

Tags: etl, akka.net

I'm new in the world of actor modeling and I am in love with the idea. But does some pattern exists for processing a batch of messages simply for bulk storage in a safe manner?

I'm afraid if I read 400 messages of expected 500 and put them in a list, if the system closes, I don't want to lose those 400 messages from the (persisted)
 mailbox. In a service bus world you could ask for a batch of messages and only when processed, commit all of them. Thank you.

Comment: Why the dowvote? Only because my english is bad?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to combine your actor system with some service bus/reliable queues, like RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus, at use actor system only for message processing.

From within Akka.NET itself, you have [persistence](http://getakka.net/docs/Persistence) extension, which can be used for storing actor state in persistent backend of your choice. It also contains a dedicated kind of an actor, `AtLeastOnceDeliveryActor` that may be used to resend messages until they will be confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

you can extend split and aggregate in your ESB to do it, I made something similar with mule ESB from long time.